Adobe form hour format
i'm trying to creat a adobe form.
I need to format a time field, but I want it to be divided into HH and MM, as in the image
enter image description here
I formatted the first custom field in "HH", when I try to enter just two digits it gives an error that the value entered does not correspond to the value, for it to accept the value I have to enter it in "HH:MM" format so that only the hours appear
enter image description here
Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong.
and if necessary, if you could give me the script, I would appreciate it because I'm new to these journeys.
help with writing the script
